# Calling a server side JsonResult method from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, ext.net

I need to call the following JsonResult method:

```
JsonResult Delete(int pubId)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new LibsysLiteContext())
        {
            var p = ctx.Publishers.Find(pubId);
            var allPublisher = ctx.Publishers.ToList();
            ctx.Publishers.Remove(p);
            var total = allPublisher.Count();
            return Json(new { success = true, data = allPublisher, total = total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new RestResult { Success = true, Data = entity, Message = "Country  has been deleted" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new RestResult { Success = true, Message = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}
```

from a js function (deleteRows):

```
var deleteRows = function () {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        'Delete Rows', 'Are you sure?',
        function(btn) {
            if (btn == 'yes') {
                var hh = Ext.getCmp('gg').deleteSelected();
                ajax({
                    //action and controller
                    url: '@Url.Action( "Publisher", "Delete")',
                    data: { "Id": Id },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                });
            }
        });
};
```

which is called by a handler of the following button:

```
X.Button().ID("bntdelete").Text("delete").Icon(Icon.Delete).Handler("deleteRows();"),
```

It didn't work at all this way! How can I move from client side to the server side from a JavaScript function?

Comment: sorry >> this line 
url: '@Url.Action( "Publisher", "Delete")'
should be replaced with
url: '@Url.Action( "Delete", "Publisher")'
since Delete is an action and Publisher is the controller 
anyway It didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

In general calling a serverside `[Direct Method]` from js you use `App.direct.<Method>();`

Comment: is your `JsonResult Delete(int pubId)`public and tagged with `[DirectMethod]`?

Comment: It's not tagged with [DirectMethod]
but It's public

Comment: as you see >> I have an Id parameter inside my model (publisher model ) >> and I think it's not correct to pass it as parameter in this way 
                                    App.direct.Delete(Id);

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have resolved this by now but in your ajax call you are defining the type as post but what you show on the controller is set as the default get.  you need to add

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int id)...
```

to your controller